# How to transfer old configuration files from Apache 2.2.22 to Apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I am new to Apache, and when i updated apache from 2.2.22 to 2.4.6 I found that the default virtual host location where I would put my mod_rewrite settings has changed.

For apache2.2.22: It was in /etc/apache2/sites_enabled/default. For apache 2.4.6, it changed, also the help document said: "NameVirtualHost directiveAs" :No longer needed and is now deprecated.

I have noted that it seems that the setting was removed from apache.conf. Here are my configuration details for Apache 2.2.22 and 2.4.6.

Can anyone tell me what I need to change in my configuration?

For apache2.2.22:/etc/apache2/sites_enabled/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride all
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
```

```
<Location />
   AuthName "CIO Internal Demo"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /liveclass_api/liveclass_callback.php>
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Location>

<Location /sp_service.php>
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

```
                                                                                   1,1           Top
```

For apache2.4.6:/etc/apache2/sites_enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

## vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

part of file apache.conf for Apache 2.4.6

```
# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Comment: What does any of that have to do with mod_rewrite?  You enable mod_rewrite by a) loading the module, b) specifying RewriteEngine on in the context you want your rules, and c) setting AllowOverride to at least FileInfo if you want to use .htaccess.

If your OS puts the Apache configuration in multiple files, figure out how the layout is used.  Ultimately it all gets combined.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i want deploy a websites with php,and i want redirect the URL with rewrite

Comment: In apache 2.4 this: `Order allow,deny  Allow from all`  is replaced by `Require all granted`

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293272/codeigniter-project-requere-index-php-after-moving-from-xampp-to-lamp-on-ubuntu/22299468#22299468

Answer (score 0):

The files and directories you are talking about look like you are on a debian linux, because the original apache directory/file layout is different.
For a general guide to migrate from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 see here [Upgrading to 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html).
Also you might have to see if debian has some information about changed directory/file structure etc.