# htaccess is not working after moving from XAMPP to LAMP on ubuntu 13.10 (Enable htaccess in apache linux server)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ubuntu, lamp

My CodeIgniter project is running successfully  on my XAMPP system with the url,

```
http://localhost/newsfeeds/users/allCategories/
```

When I move this project to another system has LAMP server on Ubuntu 13.10. To run the same page I need the url,

```
http://localhost/newsfeeds/index.php/users/allCategories/
```

I need the index.php file otherwise it shows a page not fount error.

My htaccess file is,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

How can I run the same project without index.php on both WAMPP and XAMP server ?

Comment: rewrite module is enabled?

Comment: @Rufinus yes, rewrite module is enabled

Comment: Was the `.htaccess` file moved over to the LAMP server?

Comment: `AllowOverride All` for the htdocs directory? Any messages in the error.log?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen yes the .htaccess file is also in LAMP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue.

In my server the mode rewrite is already on. But some default values need to be change on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file. Following are my changes,

First, find

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And change **AllowOverride None** to **All** and save.

Then enable mode rewrite using the command(In this case already enabeled),

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart the server,

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Run the project. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```