# CodeIgniter Remove index.php in URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I've created a `codeigniter` project in `Ubuntu` system and added following `base_url` as follows.

```
http://192.168.1.123/project/
```

If I access any other url like as follows.

```
http://192.168.1.123/project/course/view/1
```

That redirects to 'Page Not Found'. If I include `index.php` after `base_url`, Its working fine.

And I created `.htaccess` file as follows.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In `config.php` file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

changed to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

But still its not working. Please suggest soultion. The work would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you installed Apache mod_rewrite

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293272/htaccess-is-not-working-after-moving-from-xampp-to-lamp-on-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change in .htaccess file and try it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1 :**

Add this in htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 2 :**

Remove index.php in codeigniter config

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Step 3 :**

Allow overriding htaccess in Apache Configuration (Command)

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and edit the file & change to

```
AllowOverride All
```

for www folder

**Step 4 :**

Enabled apache mod rewrite (Command)

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

**Step 5 :**

Restart Apache (Command)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /project/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And, in the `config.php`:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Please, make sure the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly put .htaccess file outside application folder.**

**Then put following code in .htaccess file**

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

**Now you can refresh your url without index.php and it will work surely**

Answer (score 0):

For those using Linux, this are the steps to follow

Open the .htaccess file in the root folder of your project. This is located on the same folder with **application** folder.

Edit the content of .htaccess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

open the config file and change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Navigate to **etc/apache2** and open a folder called **apache2.conf**

Edit the **AllowOverride** from **None** to **All** as shown below

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

Open terminal and run this command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

To activate the new configurations restart apache by using this command

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

You have now successfully removed index.php from your url