# codeigniter index.php hide from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

All these steps working ?? i tried but not working on my ubuntu machine

1.Make below changes in application/config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Your Ci folder_name';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

2.Make .htacces file in your root directory using below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

3.Enable rewrite mode (if your rewrite mode is not enabled)

i. First, initiate it with the following command:

a2enmod rewrite

ii. Edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

change All AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.

iii. Restart your server with the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293272/htaccess-is-not-working-after-moving-from-xampp-to-lamp-on-ubuntu-13-10-enable/22299468#22299468

Comment: Why people never put trailing slash in base url?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed these steps before. [Remove index from CI](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Some time step 3 not work, check for httpd.conf file exist in apache folder ,then you have to check that your codebase folder path 
AllowOverride all

But before that check your folder permission, and htacces file executable or not.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/config.php`, change this

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and in `.htaccess` file(Place outside of application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```