# Moving codeigniter program from xampp to lampp

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, lampp

I just complete develop a web application using codeigniter framework in xampp. The testing done and all looks good in xampp server.

Due to production requirement, the production server is installed with lampp. I already move all the required folder and necessary settings.

The login page display correctly.. however, after success login, all the css and js did not load.. even PHP codes are not loaded as well..

Any ideas? Because I don't think it was my program because in development, we already completed the UAT. The only difference is the web server XAMPP in development and LAMPP in production.

Is there anything I should change in the setting or anything?.. Appreciate your advice.
Thank you

Note:
In browser.. it display as follows:

```
load->view('templates/header'); ?>

<text contents with no css / js>

load->view('templates/footer'); ?>
```

Comment: check you changed `base_url` at you config.php

Comment: @ShaifulIslam It is pointing to correct address..

Comment: @Julie can you inspect html and tell me url of css and js, html file is requesting?

Comment: @TouheedKhan URL pointing to correct css and js.. i open the URL and able to view the script

Comment: @Julie can you paste url here.

Comment: Can't.. its only accessible in local network.. but i notice error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at pStrength.jquery.js:163

Comment: i already check.. all the scripts are in correct folder .. it works in development server.. the only difference is dev use XAMPP and prod using LAMPP.. I just copy over the whole CI apps folder and change the necessary setting in config and database..

Comment: @Julie check this solution [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22299468/4419992]

Comment: @TouheedKhan .. I already did the changes.. still same.. -,-

Comment: are you using short php tags *<? ?>* ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142790/discussion-between-touheed-khan-and-julie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you found my answer useful **@julie**.. here is little detail and suggestion on your issue.

You're using short tags `<?` which is disabled on the production server. I would not suggest you to use short tags as it is mostly disabled on the production servers.

Please check out this answer for details. [why avoid short tags](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694)

**PS:** you can enable short code by changing this on your `php.ini`

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Comment: Thanks Touheed.. Thats really helpful.. Will update my code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Solved... Its just because I use short php tags in development. But in production need to use long php tags.

change from

```
<? $this->load->view('templates/header'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $this->load->view('templates/header'); ?>
```

Thanks @TouheedKhan and all..